# Add some text using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have mobile number series like this

```
9777358594
9861312901
8895210866
9861415461
9178146387
9853805726
9040663961
```

And I want replace them with this

```
a,9777358594
a,9861312901
a,8895210866
a,9861415461
a,9178146387
a,9853805726
a,9040663961
```

What is the regular expression to do this?

Comment: What language are you using?  And are the #s part of an array or an ordered list on an HTML page or in a DB?

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not for general text manipulation. It's usually possible on a framework basis to replace the result of a regex search, but you need to specify the language with which you're working.

Comment: @zneak It doesn't have to be. Text editors such as Notepad++ have replace feature based on regular expressions.

Comment: @eyazici, I think we're kind of saying the same thing. OP still has to tell the software/language to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching pattern should be `([0-9]+)` and replace pattern should be `a,\1`.

If you are using a specific language (eg. PHP, JAVA etc.) it may slightly differ.

Answer (score 0):

Won't that be much easier/cleaner with simpler string operations?

```
serial_no = sprintf('a,%s',serial_no);
```

Comment: If it's for a programming language, yes it will.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vim, try:

`%s/^\d\+/a,&/g`

or simpler:

`%s/^/a,/g`